# During binary tree insertion and traversal I get a segmentaion fault

Tags: c++, binary-tree

```
#include <iostream>

struct node {
    int val;
    node * left, * right;

    node(int value) : val(value), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};
void insert(node * &root, int val) {
        if(!root)
            root = new node(val);
        else {
            if(val <= root->val)
                insert(root->left, val);
            else
                insert(root->right, val);
        }
}

void inorder(node *root) {
    if(root == NULL)
        return ;

    inorder(root->left);
    std::cout << root->val << " ";
    inorder(root->right);
}

int main(){ 
    node *root = NULL;
    int arr[] = {7,3,8,6};

    for(auto i:arr)
        insert(root, arr[i]);
    inorder(root);
    std::cout << std::  endl;

    return 0;
}
```

all of this is compiled with c++11 on ubuntu 16.04.1 using gcc 5.4.0
the program gives me a segmentation fault. However when i manually create new node in the tree the inorder traversal works just fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your range for, when you call insert `insert(root, arr[i])` you just want `i`, not `arr[i]`. So change it to `insert(root, i);` simply.